# Powerpoint Add-in for creating video

Tags: office-js

I'm investigating if it's possible to rebuild a powerpoint addin from VSTO to an Office Add-in (javascript). In the current VSTO addin we convert the presentation to mp4 with the CreateVideo method.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff759971(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
But I cant find this method in the documentation for the javascript api. Is this possible with the javascript API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but that feature is not supported in the JavaScript Office APIs. But it is an interesting idea. Please suggest it at [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).